# target="_blank" not working in a tag SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, html, js, isblank

The target="_blank" not working for a tag when used in SharePoint online.

Comment: Could you try to be a bit more specific on how and where you are using this - maybe include a sample of your code?

Answer (score 8):

Make the **data-interception="off"**, see the below example :

```
<a href="https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/..." data-interception="off" target="_blank"   rel="noopener noreferrer">My other page</a>
```

Refer to the below articles for more details :

- [SharePoint Online not respecting target="_blank" anymore?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/sharepoint-online-not-respecting-target-quot-blank-quot-anymore/m-p/875769)
- https://julieturner.net/2018/08/spfx-anchor-tags-hitting-the-target/

Comment: Thanks guy's I will try and check if this works out......

Comment: Thank you so much!!!